# WolframAlpha XML parsing error

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, xml

I am using the `WolframAlpha` command to automated solution sets of homework exercises. Here is an sample usage, although this can happen with many different examples:

```
WolframAlpha["limit (1 + k)^10/(10*k^10) as k -> Infinity", {{"Limit", 2}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Limit__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

Every so often, I receive the error message:

```
XML`Parser`XMLGetString::prserr: The main XML document cannot be empty at Line: 6 Character: 1.
```

When I reissue the command, it returns fine. That would seem to indicate that it is a timeout issue. OTOH, using the `TimeConstraint` option returns a different message.

Therefore, I would like to know what causes this, in order to build a workaround. Alternatively, to know (programmatically) that it happened (in some error value), in order to reissue the command.

TYVM.

Comment: Can you include the command you are running? The fact that `TimeConstrained` returns a different error does not surprise me, since the failure mode becomes different (your code is aborted locally rather than failing).

Comment: @MarcoB, thank you for your reply. I have included a sample invocation, although the error message can either happen or not, with many different types of invocations.

Comment: 1) This is likely an intermittent connection problem. 2) how to avoid it -> That will depend on what is actually being returned upon error. `WolframAlpha` returns a `RawBoxes` object when the call works. I could not reproduce the error, so I don't know what would be returned in that case (maybe `$Failed`?), but you could check for an unexpected `Head` in the return value. Maybe wrap `wa = WolframAlpha[...]` in `While` and re-evaluate it until `Head[wa]` returns `RawBoxes`?

Comment: And an aside: I know that this is not your point, but in the particular example you propose, I personally would find the results of `Apart[(1 + k)^10/(10*k^10)]` much clearer in illustrating why the limit is $1/10$ than the explanation given by W|A.

Comment: @MarcoB, excellent suggestion. I ran this 50 times -- no problems. I ran it another 50 times and "fortunately" the problem reared its ugly `Head` and it equaled: `Missing`. Thanx again.

Comment: Please note two caveats: 1) A valid result of `WolframAlpha` can also be `List`, so one cannot only look for `RawBoxes`. 2) `Missing` can also be a *valid* result, if no such result is available (e.g., if requesting a non-existing step-by-step solution to a problem), so one cannot look for the returned `Head` to *not* be `Missing`. So, I still would prefer to check for some "global" error status, that the XML parsing error occurred. Thanx.

Comment: Solution: use `Check` or `MessageList`.

Comment: All that sounds insightful and very promising. Please summarize your findings in a self-answer to your own question. Those are encouraged here, as you probably already know.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you again to @MarcoB for guiding me.

Due to all of the possible results from `WolframAlpha`, it would be difficult to tag what is a valid result, and what suffered from what is apparently a connection problem. Specifically, `Missing` could be either.

Therefore, the way to go to is to check the system whether an error occurred, either a specific one (like parse error mentioned in the question), or *any* error. This can easily be accomplished with `Check` or `MessageList`.